# Beam python silently drops type checking for unsupported types?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I had the following pipeline:

```
from typing import Sequence, List

import apache_beam as beam


def add_type(x) -> int:
    return x

# no type error with Sequence, type error with List.
def print_with_type(x: Sequence[int]):
    print(x)


with beam.Pipeline(argv=["--type_check_additional", "all"]) as pipeline:
    lines = (
            pipeline
            | beam.Create([1, 2])
            | beam.Map(add_type)
            # removing this line should trigger type error
            # | beam.combiners.ToList()
            | beam.Map(print_with_type))
```

I expected a type checking error when building the pipeline, but did not get it. Only after much debugging did I realize that I should use `List` instead of `Sequence`.

Is this expected, as `Sequence` is one of the supported types ([doc](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-type-safety/#parameterized-type-hints))?
Is it possible to have a warning in such cases?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `List` instead of `Sequence`. In the link of the [docs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-type-safety/#parameterized-type-hints) you have referenced is no `Sequence` listed, but only `List`. Executing your code with sequence in [Apache play](https://play.beam.apache.org/), I obtain the following Info:
[image]

which explains why it is not throwing any typing hint error. If you switch to `List`, everything works as expected.

Btw, I would recommend using `with_input_types` and `with_output_types`. If your pipeline gets more complex, this approach is more readable in my opinion, since you do not have to look up all of your custom classes and methods for understanding the types, e.g.

```py
from typing import Sequence, List
import apache_beam as beam

def add_type(x) -> int:
  return x

# no type error with Sequence, type error with List.
def print_with_type(x: Sequence[int]):  # <- is ignored
  print(x)
 
with beam.Pipeline(argv=["--type_check_additional", "all"]) as pipeline:
  lines = (
    pipeline
    | beam.Create([1, 2])
    | beam.Map(add_type).with_output_types(int)   # <- is checked
    # removing this line should trigger type error
    # | beam.combiners.ToList()
    | beam.Map(print_with_type).with_input_types(List[int])  # <- is checked
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case the type is not a `List` but an `int` for the current element in the `PCollection` :

```py
from typing import Sequence, List

import apache_beam as beam


def add_type(x) -> int:
    return x

# The expected type is int
def print_with_type(x: int):
    print(x)


with beam.Pipeline(argv=["--type_check_additional", "all"]) as pipeline:
    lines = (
            pipeline
            | beam.Create([1, 2])
            | beam.Map(add_type)
            # | beam.combiners.ToList()
            | beam.Map(print_with_type))
```

When I am testing with `str` type instead of `int`, I have the expected `type_hints` error :

```py
from typing import Sequence, List

import apache_beam as beam


def add_type(x) -> int:
    return x

# Test with the bad type
def print_with_type(x: str):
    print(x)


with beam.Pipeline(argv=["--type_check_additional", "all"]) as pipeline:
    lines = (
            pipeline
            | beam.Create([1, 2])
            | beam.Map(add_type)
            # | beam.combiners.ToList()
            | beam.Map(print_with_type))
```

The error is :

```
 raise TypeCheckError(
                'Type hint violation for \'{label}\': requires {hint} but got '
                '{actual_type} for {arg}\nFull type hint:\n{debug_str}'.format(
                    label=self.label,
                    hint=hint,
                    actual_type=bindings[arg],
                    arg=arg,
                    debug_str=type_hints.debug_str()))
E           apache_beam.typehints.decorators.TypeCheckError: Type hint violation for 'Map(print_with_type)': requires <class 'str'> but got <class 'int'> for x
E           Full type hint:
E           IOTypeHints[inputs=((<class 'str'>,), {}), outputs=((Any,), {})]
```

When I am testing with a `List` of `int`, I have again the expected error :

```py
rom typing import Sequence, List

import apache_beam as beam


def add_type(x) -> int:
    return x

# Test with the bad type
def print_with_type(x: List[int]):
    print(x)


with beam.Pipeline(argv=["--type_check_additional", "all"]) as pipeline:
    lines = (
            pipeline
            | beam.Create([1, 2])
            | beam.Map(add_type)
            # | beam.combiners.ToList()
            | beam.Map(print_with_type))
```

The error is :

```
E           apache_beam.typehints.decorators.TypeCheckError: Type hint violation for 'Map(print_with_type)': requires List[int] but got <class 'int'> for x
```

But when I am testing with `Sequence`, I don't have the expected error.

According to the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-type-safety/#parameterized-type-hints), the following types are supported for the type checking :

```
Tuple[T, U]
Tuple[T, ...]
List[T]
KV[T, U]
Dict[T, U]
Set[T]
FrozenSet[T]
Iterable[T]
Iterator[T]
Generator[T]
PCollection[T]
```

`Sequence` type is not part of this list that’s why it was ignored.

But it makes no sense to pass a `List` or a `Sequence` in your example, because the expected type is a `int` not a `List`.

Comment: Your last sentence is exactly my question. Sorry about the confusion: the commented-out line in my example is meant to trigger the type checking error.

Comment: If you put a List or str, the type checking is correctly applied

Comment: The type checking is correctly applied for all the types I tested except of Sequence. But it makes no sense to pass a List or a Sequence because the expected type is a int not a List.

Comment: For example, If you pass a str instead of the expected int type, the type checking is correctly applied.

Comment: According to the documentation the sequence type is not a supported type, I edited my answer to explain this. But as I explained previously, it makes no sense to use Sequence in your example because the expected type is a int.